# How to create file base of condition using python

Tags: python

I am bit stuck with this approach not getting how to proceed with it

**Case 1 :** Check directory present or not , if not present create Directory and one file inside it and return that filename : ABC_20210730.txt

**Case 2 :** If Directory present, return the filename inside it [ Only 1 latest file name which as current date in it , example : ABC_20210730.txt ]

**Case 3 :** If Directory present but no file present inside it create the new file and return filename : ABC_20210730.txt

**My code :**

```
import os
import logging
import sys
import glob

logging.basicConfig(filename='C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\JUL\\log.txt', level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s : %(message)s', filemode='w')

def checkfileexist(file_path, search_file_name):
    try:
        var_pth = str(file_path)
        var_fle = str(file_name)
        var_full = var_pth + var_fle

        if var_pth is None or var_pth == '':
            logging.error("Path parameter is empty")
            raise TypeError('Path parameter is empty')
        else:
            pass
            logging.info(f'Path : {var_pth}')
        
        if search_file_name is None or search_file_name == '':
            logging.error("Search file name parameter is empty")
            raise TypeError('Search file name parameter is empty')
        else:
            pass
            logging.info(f'Path : {search_file_name}')

        if os.path.exists(var_full):
            sfilename=glob.glob(file_path + '/' + search_file_name + '*' + '*.txt' )
            return sfilename
        
        if not os.path.exists(var_full):
            os.mkdir(var_full)
            with open(var_full+'/'+'ABC_20210730.txt',"w") as f:
                f.write('')
            return f
        
        if not os.file.exists(var_full+'/'+search_file_name):

            with open(var_full+'/'+'ABC_20210730.txt',"w") as f:
                f.write('')
            return f

    except:
        logging.error(f"ERRO : {erron} ")
        sys.exit()


checkfileexist('C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\JUL\\', 'ABX')
```

Comment: What is the problem (edit the question to describe it)? What happens?

Comment: If this is copied from your project, you have a couple of mistakes in `var_fle = str(file_name)`, which should be `var_fle = str(search_file_name)` maybe?
Also, in `except` block you need to assign the error variable like `except Exception as Error` and then you can use it in `logging.error(f"Error : {Error}")`

Comment: When concatenating path names it is best to use `os.path.join`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to write code

Thanks to all the contributors for helping : @[Derek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15518276/derek) and @[Tõnis Piip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5967602/t%C3%B5nis-piip)

I case require any modification in code , feel free to edit and had working code

This below code work for me and tested on my system

**My code :**

```
import os
import glob
import logging

path_name = 'C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\JUL\\'
sfilename = 'log'

logging.basicConfig(filename='C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\JUL\\demo.txt', level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s : %(message)s', filemode='w')

def returnfilename(path_name, sfilename):

    varname = ''

    try:

        if path_name is None or path_name == '':
            raise TypeError('Path parameter is empty')
        else:
            pass

        if sfilename is None or sfilename == '':
            raise TypeError('Search parameter is empty')
        else:
            pass

        # If path does not exist then create folder and file inside it
        if not os.path.exists(path_name):
            os.mkdir(path_name)
            fullname = path_name + '/' + sfilename + '.txt'
            with open(fullname, 'w') as fd:
                fd.write('')
            varname = fullname

        # If path exist , then return latest file name from that path
        if os.path.exists(path_name):
            var = glob.glob(f'{path_name}/{sfilename}.*')
            var.sort(), var.reverse()
            newpickname = var[0]
            head, tail = os.path.split(newpickname)
            varname = tail

    # If path exist , then return latest file name from that path , if not exist it will throw exception IndexError
    except IndexError:
        fullname = path_name + '/' + sfilename + '.txt'
        with open(fullname, 'w') as fd:
            fd.write('')
            varname = fullname

    except Exception as er:
        logging.error(f"{er}")

    return varname


getfile = returnfilename('', sfilename)
print(getfile)
```